# How to disable the skype ads (advertisement)?

Tags: windows, skype, advertisements

The Skype client shows a disturbing colored ad at the bottom of the client. The ad is unnecessary and only takes away important space for the contact list.

**How can I remove that permanentely?**

[image]

Even after clicking the close sign on the ad, the ad appears again each time I open/click Skype again...

Comment: Whether it's unnecessary or not is a matter of opinion. Microsoft, not being a charity, might think it's necessary.

Comment: Correct, but I'm aware of that Skype can make unlimited* calls or its other features. Microsoft does not need to remind me all the time. Also a Word 2010 does not remind you the whole time that there's a new version or that it can handle automatic reference lists or similar ;-)

Comment: No, Word doesn't. Not yet, anyway. But then you paid a whole load of money for Word. You got Skype for free. Ads are how they subsidise giving it you for free.

Comment: Detailed blog how you can remove ads from Skype: http://sforsuresh.in/remove-ads-from-skype-on-window/

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I got rid of this like that. Go to `Tools` > `Options` and uncheck `Promotions` and `Help and Skype tips`.

[image: Skype **ver.5.1.32.104**]

Additionaly, if you go to `Tools` > `Options` > `Privacy` > `Show Advanced Options` in the bottom of the window, you will see something about `Microsoft targeted ads...`, unticked this and restarted Skype altogether and so long I haven't seen any ads anywhere (thanks to juanm55)

Comment: This is not enough to hide the advertisements

Comment: Well, yes, it's not enough. But if you carefully look at the screenshot OP provided, you'll see that he wants to remove promotions, but NOT ads.

Comment: At least for me, after disabling these 2 options I still see advertisements at the bottom of the client, very similar to the one in the screenshot the OP provided. And after reading the question again, I would say these are the ads the user wanted to remove.

Comment: It actually worked for me.  Just have to sign out and re-login again.  Otherwise it's still there.

Comment: Additionaly, if you go to 'Tools' > 'Options' > 'Privacy' > 'Show Advanced Options' in the bottom of the window, you will see something about "Microsoft targeted ads..."  I unticked this, and restarted Skype altogether and so long I haven't seen any ads anywhere

Comment: @JuanManuelLF That does it. Thanks. Should be added to the answer.

Answer (score 71):

Put this in your [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29):

```
127.0.0.1     rad.msn.com
```

**Update**: nZeus suggests using the following:

```
127.0.0.1     rad.msn.com
127.0.0.1     g.msn.com
127.0.0.1     live.rads.msn.com
127.0.0.1     ads1.msn.com
127.0.0.1     static.2mdn.net
127.0.0.1     ads2.msads.net
127.0.0.1     a.ads2.msads.net
127.0.0.1     b.ads2.msads.net
127.0.0.1     ad.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1     ac3.msn.com
127.0.0.1     ec.atdmt.com
127.0.0.1     msntest.serving-sys.com
127.0.0.1     sO.2mdn.net
127.0.0.1     aka-cdn-ns.adtech.de
127.0.0.1     secure.flashtalking.com
127.0.0.1     cdn.atdmt.com
127.0.0.1     apps.skype.com
```

I haven't tested the latter. The first one worked for me.

Comment: Just in case somebody does not know what this does, this makes any attempt to connect to `rad.msn.com` impossible by making its IP point to `localhost`. I'm pretty sure it's safe to do, but I don't know if it works (didn't test it).

Comment: For future reference, location of the hosts file in Windows XP and later (including Windows 8) is `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`. Just open it in Notepad and add the line in this answer.

Comment: Works on OSX, but does leave a big white square within the 'Skype Home' pane.

Comment: That hostname isn't enough to do anything for me.  I put together a list of suggested hostnames to block here: http://superuser.com/a/708801/130906

Comment: there are other lists of skype ad servers but this one did the trick. 
confirmed to still work for win-Skype 6.13.0.104 running win7. thank you!

Comment: Thank you, Pere and @leetNightshade. It is working in Skype v6.13.32.104 on Win 7.

Comment: Please also include this line `127.0.0.1             ad-emea.doubleclick.net` Found [here](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/skype-ad-spam-disable/td-p/12156).

Comment: I prefer to use ip address 0.0.0.0 since I work as web dev and certainly don't want unwanted apps to contact my local http server!

Comment: Nice. I need this for my Macbook because constant 30% CPU usage courtesy of Flash via Skype Ad is simply **criminal**... Skype times out for about 30sec on startup desperately trying to phone up its ad. Then gives up. Yeah, that's what I thought.

Comment: I wrote a script that does this https://github.com/awatertrevi/skype-ad-blocker :)

Comment: This list is still blocking the ads on mac! Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

**None of the above methods work for the newer versions of Skype** A new method has emerged that works in Skype 6.13 and Skype 6.14, works on Windows using Internet Explorer settings, from [Chris123NT](http://www.chris123nt.com/2014/02/16/get-rid-of-skype-ads-in-chat-screen-6-13/):

Open up Control Panel > Internet Options.

[image]

Security > Restricted Sites > Sites

[image]

Type in `https://apps.skype.com`, and click `Add`.

[image]

Again, click `Add`, then `Close`, then `OK`. Now open up Skype, click on the home button, and the ad banner should disappear and not come back!

Comment: OSX users can achieve the same by typing the following in a terminal window:

    `sudo su && echo "127.0.0.1  apps.skype.com" >> /etc/hosts`

Comment: This works on v6.21, however it will also disable the Facebook integration, at on the `Home` view.

Comment: +1 Disabling Facebook integration seems like a  plus to me. If I want to see Facebook stream, I'd go to Facebook not Skype. ;)

Comment: works in skype version 7 win7

Answer (score 13):

**>>Note that the steps below won't work in Skype 6.9 or later<<**

To get rid of advertisements upgrade to Skype Premium (from http://www.skype.com/en/premium/):

[image]

To disable promotions (from https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA1111/where-are-alerts-and-messages-displayed):

1. Click Tools > Options > Notifications.
2. Select Alerts & messages.
3. Under Show messages about… tick the boxes for the alerts and messages you wish to receive.
4. Click Save to update your settings.

Comment: On OSX (Skype v6.9) there's no comparable option under Preferences/Notifications.

Comment: I would like to minus you, but I can't... yet

Comment: @nZeus Why is that?

Comment: Because it doesn't work. See here - http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Skype-Premium-subscription-showing-ads-scam/td-p/2950141
Total morons work at Skype support and I'm still fighting.

Comment: **1)** I edited my answer and added that the steps explained won't work in Skype 6.9 or later. **2)** I'm sorry to hear that you have trouble getting rid of those ads, but don't take it out on me, the answer was correct at the time of writing one year ago. I don't use Skype anymore, but you do - if you find out how to fix it edit my answer (as explained in *Improve posts by editing or commenting* in http://superuser.com/tour) or write your own answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Updated DNS block list; works as of version `6.21.85.104`.  Add this to your hosts file (typically something like `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`).  Works best with IPv6, since `100::/64` is a "drop-all" prefix.  Works with IPv4 as long as you don't have anything listening on `127.6.6.6`.  You can use `127.0.0.1`, but I would advise against that, since the connection won't die immediately if you have another program listening on port 443.  (`127.0.0.0/8` is loopback, not just `127.0.0.1`.)

```
127.6.6.6 a.ads2.msads.net
127.6.6.6 ac3.msn.com
127.6.6.6 ads1.msads.net
127.6.6.6 ads2.msads.net
127.6.6.6 b.ads2.msads.net
127.6.6.6 cdn.adnxs.com
127.6.6.6 cdn.adnxs.com.edgesuite.net
127.6.6.6 cdn.atdmt.com
127.6.6.6 live.rads.msn.com
127.6.6.6 rad.msn.com
127.6.6.6 secure.flashtalking.com
127.6.6.6 wildcard.msads.net
127.6.6.6 wildcard.msads.net.edgekey.net
100::1 a.ads2.msads.net
100::1 ac3.msn.com
100::1 ads1.msads.net
100::1 ads2.msads.net
100::1 b.ads2.msads.net
100::1 cdn.adnxs.com
100::1 cdn.adnxs.com.edgesuite.net
100::1 cdn.atdmt.com
100::1 live.rads.msn.com
100::1 rad.msn.com
100::1 secure.flashtalking.com
100::1 wildcard.msads.net
100::1 wildcard.msads.net.edgekey.net
```

Comment: Where did you get these? Is this `wildcard.msads.net` correct or is it supposed to be `*.msads.net`? * is commonly a wildcard after all, you just have the word instead of the character.

Comment: @leetNightshade I got them using a mix of Wireshark, Process Explorer, and good old trial-and-error  That is literally `wildcard.msads.net`, not `*.msads.net`.  Microsoft has some weird naming schemes, apparently.

Answer (score 2):

I created a Windows Batch script to help remove the ADS from Skype, it can add a blacklist to Windows hosts file and also change a parameter on the Skype user settings file.

This way I was able to remove all ADS from Skype 7, including the ADS block that appears on the right side of the chat.

This script was tested on Skype 7.85.105.101 and is intended to run on Windows Vista, 7 or 8.

You can get the script here: [disable_skype_ads.zip](http://www.mediafire.com/download/re10fb46yu5vi00/disable_skype_ads.zip).
Unpack the zip and read the readme.txt file to know how to use it.

If you find any bugs or have suggestions, please add a comment bellow, so I can fix/improve it.

Comment: Downloading and running code from an untrusted source isn't really the best idea. Could you post the code here in your answer or [create a gist snippet on github](https://gist.github.com/) so people can look at the code without downloading a foreign zip file?

Comment: @culix and the paranoid: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0111365ffd7eaf0312ce3dbec3737feb

Answer (score 1):

The way that works for me (version 6.11.0.102) is the following:

1. Go to Tools -> Change Language -> Edit Skype Language File...
2. Navigate to s_LANGUAGE_NAME (line 129 on my English language file)
3. Change the string to something else that is arbitrary (I use "NoAds")
4. Click "Save As..." and save the file to what you named it (for me, "NoAds.lang")
5. Finally, make sure this language is selected as the current language in the Tools -> Change Language menu (if it isn't, use the "Open Skype Language File" option to locate and load it)

From what I remember about this trick... since the ads are targeted towards language, putting in a bogus string value will essentially cause Skype to fail at finding an advert to display, and in turn, it will not display one.

This has worked for me on multiple installs of this same version of Skype, and in versions past as well.

Note: I also do this in tandem with what Volodymyr does in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a program which hides the biggest and in my opinion most annoying Skype ad.

One can find it at:

- https://sourceforge.net/p/skypeadremover
- https://www.assembla.com/spaces/slipstream/wiki/Skype_Ad_Remover

Just remember, as it says in the `README.txt`, that Skype must be used in the `Default View` mode (`View -> Default View`) for the thing to work.