# Disable advertisements on Skype?

Tags: windows-7, skype, advertisements

An ad titled "Two friends who've never met" recently appeared on my girlfriend's Skype. The ad appears above the name of the contact she is currently speaking to and can't be disabled via the ad options build into Skype. How can we disable this ad?

The ad looks like this:

[image: The problem]

**Things we have tried**:

- Tried unchecking "Help and Skype tips" and "Promotions" under "Alerts & messages" in the options menu.
- Tried changing the language file per Primemover's answer [here](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Skype-5-pop-up-ads/td-p/3996)

> B.  Rename The English language file.  Procedure listed below;
>
> 1. Click Tools >> Change Language >> Edit Skype Language File...
> 2. The Skype - Language File Editor window will open, click the Save As button
> 3. Enter Standard English as filename , Save it on your desktop or in any folder you want.
> 4. Click Tools >> Change Language >> Load Skype Language File..., then browse and select the Standard English language file.
> 5. Restart Skype   Again, this suggestion though proven to be working, is not from, suggested, or endorsed by Skype or any of its
>      staff.  So try at your own risk.  This method should only be used, if
>      and only if, those advertisements are seriously affecting your
>      interest in using the Skype client.

- Tried downgrading to Skype version 6.10, 6.9, 5.10, and 4.2

I can confirm that I've never seen ads like this before, nor have other contacts I've asked. Is there anything else we can try to disable this?

**Note**: This originally started on Skype 6.10 but has persisted across older versions upon downgrading.

**Edit**: [How to disable the skype ads (advertisement)?](https://superuser.com/questions/547807/how-to-disable-the-skype-ads-advertisement?rq=1) fails to answer the question I have posted. This is not a duplicate. The question linked appears to target a different group of ads (promotions) and is unrelated.

Comment: Linking [Close votes on a question that isn't off topic?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/7385/236545) for posterity. If anyone finds issue with this question, please explain your reasoning here.

Comment: I know you said the answers to the other question did not solve your problem, but did you try upgrading to Premium as suggested by http://superuser.com/a/547815/6091 and http://www.skype.com/en/premium/? Perhaps you also need to sign out and sign back in after upgrading to Premium.

Comment: @rob premium is kind of a last resort. I'll upgrade to it if I can find no other solution, otherwise I'd much rather a solution that doesn't require me to pay Microsoft to get rid of the ads.

Comment: where does the advert direct when it is clicked on?

Comment: Seems this is a legit skype marketing campaign, I have yet to see this inside the skype appication (5.10, all other versions suck)

Comment: Have you tried blocking them using the hosts file as described [here](http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.htm)?

Comment: I really hope someone will make a patch for Skype like the one we had for MSN Messenger. Which blocked out all the ads.

Comment: @DanteTheEgregore I would vote to close it, and did, as "unclear what you're asking". The entire problem description consists of two words, "experiencing issues", but doesn't even try to explain what those issues are at all. There might be a fix for these "issues", but without even a single symptom, I don't see how anyone could even begin to investigate. Maybe someone is experiencing the same problem and already found a fix -- how would they know?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You're joking, right? Have you actually read the question? I'm asking how to block the ad in the picture. I explained that to anyone with even basic reading abilities. I've listed the symptoms and I've listed what I've tried to fix the issue. "How can I block this ad? I've tried x, y, and z solutions that have been suggested before, but none worked. Am I doing something wrong? Are there further options I can try as well?" is a pretty black and white question.

Comment: @DanteTheEgregore No, I'm serious. You haven't listed a single symptom. You just said she was "experiencing issues". You've asserted that you think that disabling the ad will solve the issues, but there's no way we can make any sense out of that because *we don't know what the issues are*. This is a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/167586) -- you've talked an awful lot about your proposed solution to the problem but almost nothing at all about *what the problem is*.

Comment: @DanteTheEgregore Maybe you should reword the first paragraph of your question. If the issue is the ad itself you should make that clear. If you have another issue caused by the ad you should add that in the first paragraph.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Let's take a second and examine the question I asked. First there's the title: "*Disable advertisements on Skype?*". This states the core problem of the question, though, do to the character limit, fails to cover it effectively. I then stated "*My girlfriend recently began experiencing issues with the "Two friends who've never met" ad on Skype.*" which you take issue with for reasons beyond my comprehension. After stating this, I expand on the **ISSUE** by stating "*The ad keeps appearing above the name of the contact she is currently talking to and can't be gotten rid of.*"

Comment: @DavidSchwartz After stating this, I include a picture of the ad mentioned in the question for further clarification and list solutions I've found online that seem to solve my **ISSUE** by blocking all ads in Skype. The **ISSUE** with these solutions, is that they fail to block the ad I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @DanteTheEgregore Right. You have some kind of problem with that ad -- "experiencing issues". Your suggested solution is blocking that ad, which you expect will solve the problem, whatever it is. But there might be other solutions to that problem or blocking the ad might not solve it or how you block it might affect whether it's solved or not. Someone else might have the same problem with the ad, but they can't tell. This is a very, very poor question. I would, and did, vote to close it as "unclear what you're asking". How would I know if I had replicated the problem?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz What, tell me what, is so wrong with "Here's an ad. People all over the internet, even here on Superuser, say you should be able to get rid of ads on Skype by following **X** steps. I followed **X** steps, and all the other ads are gone, but this one ad still remains. I want this ad gone. I don't like this ad. Can I get rid of this ad in a way similar to the ways used to get rid of the similar ads? Is there an altogether different solution for getting rid of this singular, nuisance of an ad?"

Comment: @DanteTheEgregore Nothing. That would have been a good question -- it would have been clear what you were asking. You know how to ask a good question -- why did you ask such a terrible one?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That's the question I asked. ._.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I reworded the initial paragraph so as not to offend your glaring discomfort with the psuedo-ambiguous. Please stop harassing me now.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could try editing your hosts file and pointing the offending ad's hostname to 127.0.0.1.

Edit the file `%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

To the bottom of the file add the entry:

```
127.0.0.1 hostname-of-the-ad
```

Where hostname is the hostname of the ad. For example, if the ad's URL is http://www.some-ad-service.com/, you would use www.some-ad-service.com as the hostname (thanks slhck, for pointing this out).

Save the file.

Now whenever your machine attempts to access the ad's URL the request will be sent to your local machine instead. The end result being that the ad is blocked.

Comment: A hosts file does not take URLs. URLs are resource locators—the hosts file really just blocks hostnames.

Comment: Yes, the hosts file assigns hostnames to IP addresses, but in this case the URL _is_ the hostname that we want to assign.

Comment: Well, it's not really. A hostname is part of the URL. A URL is only valid with a protocol scheme. I'm just saying it might be good to clarify your answer to mention that you cannot put `http://example.com/some/ad.jpg` in there, but only `example.com`. (It would also be interesting to know how to find where the ad is coming from.)

Comment: @slhck Yes, you are absolutely right, thank you. I have updated my answer to provide a more clear explaination. As for finding where the ad is coming from, you could always use a protocol analyzer like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) on the local machine to figure out where the request is being sent to.

Comment: ```127.0.0.1     rad.msn.com```

Comment: Actually there is a site which holds a good example of hosts file http://someonewhocares.org/hosts/ it will bolck a lot of messy things in internet

Answer (score 38):

Extending off of Matt's answer, since he doesn't include possible hostnames to block.

---

You need to add entries to your `hosts` file, typically located here: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

These are hostnames you'll want to block, by adding them to the `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1             sO.2mdn.net
127.0.0.1         static.2mdn.net
127.0.0.1            cdn.adnxs.com
127.0.0.1  cdn.adnxs.com.edgesuite.net
127.0.0.1     aka-cdn-ns.adtech.de
127.0.0.1            cdn.atdmt.com
127.0.0.1             ec.atdmt.com
127.0.0.1             ad.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1        ad-emea.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1         secure.flashtalking.com
127.0.0.1           ads1.msads.net
127.0.0.1           ads2.msads.net
127.0.0.1         a.ads2.msads.net
127.0.0.1         b.ads2.msads.net
127.0.0.1            ac3.msn.com
127.0.0.1           ads1.msn.com
127.0.0.1           flex.msn.com
127.0.0.1              g.msn.com
127.0.0.1            rad.msn.com
127.0.0.1      live.rads.msn.com
127.0.0.1        msntest.serving-sys.com
::1                   sO.2mdn.net
::1               static.2mdn.net
::1                  cdn.adnxs.com
::1        cdn.adnxs.com.edgesuite.net
::1           aka-cdn-ns.adtech.de
::1                  cdn.atdmt.com
::1                   ec.atdmt.com
::1                   ad.doubleclick.net
::1              ad-emea.doubleclick.net
::1               secure.flashtalking.com
::1                 ads1.msads.net
::1                 ads2.msads.net
::1               a.ads2.msads.net
::1               b.ads2.msads.net
::1                  ac3.msn.com
::1                 ads1.msn.com
::1                 flex.msn.com
::1                    g.msn.com
::1                  rad.msn.com
::1            live.rads.msn.com
::1              msntest.serving-sys.com
```

Source of hostnames here: [wikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Stop-All-the-Ads-in-Hotmail), [Skype forum](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/skype-ad-spam-disable/td-p/12156), [Skype forum #2](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/skype-ad-spam-disable/td-p/12156), and a commenter Jason at [Avangardo](http://blog.avangardo.com/2013/02/how-to-block-ads-in-skype/). Just a warning, but Microsoft Security Essentials (MSE) may think your hosts file was hijacked, so if you have issues make sure to allow the changes through MSE.

**Also**, you may need to restart your computer, in case flushing the dns cache doesn't work.  It seems when you make a lot of changes to the hosts file Windows doesn't reload it.

On Skype 6.14 it re-enabled these options, you'll want to disable (uncheck) them:
[image]
[image]

---

**A new method has emerged that works in Skype 6.13 and Skype 6.14**, works on Windows using Internet Explorer settings, from [Chris123NT](http://www.chris123nt.com/2014/02/16/get-rid-of-skype-ads-in-chat-screen-6-13/):

Open up Control Panel > Internet Options.

[image]

Security > Restricted Sites > Sites

[image]

Type in `https://apps.skype.com`, and click `Add`.

[image]

Again, click `Add`, then `Close`, then `OK`. Now open up Skype, click on the home button, and hopefully the ad banner should disappear and not come back!

Comment: That's awesome! `rad.msn.com` is the only domain I've been able to locate until now.

Comment: Thanks @leetNightshade, it's working so far. Let's hope Microsoft doesn't add more domains!

Comment: Update: Nope. Ads are back. What other domains can we block?

Comment: @Churro I think we might have to resort to blocking the ip address of the server?  From looking at Process Explorer I got the feeling Skype was bypassing the domain name lookup.   I even tried using PeerBlock in the hopes one of their ad lists would block them, to no avail; I also searched iblocklist.com.  So, looks like we'll have to  compile the list ourselves. This site is probably out of date, but could be used as reference: http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r27274447-Block-Ads-in-Skype  I'll look into the issue this week. ProcMon will be useful in doing this, monitors all network traffic.

Comment: Thank you for keeping this up to date, every time I see another "Hot singles in your area !!1!" ad, I come here and get the latest patch for my hosts file.

Comment: @David You're welcome! I know it annoys a lot of people in my office, so for their sanity I try to make sure I research and stay on top of the latest methods for dealing with this.

Comment: The last option worked for me. Could you move it to a new answer, so that it can be voted for, independent of the other options?

Comment: @Glen Little I have the last option here, is that fine w/ you? http://superuser.com/a/736557/130906

Comment: @leetNightshade Yup,  I was able to vote it up,  so I'm happy :)

Comment: Are you sure that wildcards are allowed in the Windows hosts file?

Comment: @Arjan Yeah it doesn't without adding a custom DNS Proxy. Fixing. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Blocking apps.skype.com worked great for a while but now it blocks emoticons too. I switched to Skype for Business at work which doesn't have ads (yet).

Comment: @User5910 Emoticons seem to work fine for me.