# How do I disable ads on Skype?

Tags: skype

I've already disabled the ads in the contact list, but in the chat window, there are still ads popping up overhead.  These are from Google Ad Choices and there is no way to close them.  I can't get the ad to close like you can for the ones in the contact list. There's no little X you can push, no options that let me opt out of getting them that I have found.

This is really starting to get on my nerves. Nothing I've tried so far has gotten rid of this thing.

Comment: This has the same answers as [this](http://superuser.com/questions/547807/how-to-disable-the-skype-ads-advertisement) question (however this question isn't a duplicate in my opinion).

Comment: Detailed blog how you can remove ads from Skype: http://sforsuresh.in/remove-ads-from-skype-on-window/

Answer (score 12):

Get [Skype Premium](http://www.skype.com/en/premium/) or add these to your hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1     rad.msn.com
127.0.0.1     g.msn.com
127.0.0.1     live.rads.msn.com
127.0.0.1     ads1.msn.com
127.0.0.1     static.2mdn.net
127.0.0.1     ads2.msads.net
127.0.0.1     a.ads2.msads.net
127.0.0.1     b.ads2.msads.net
127.0.0.1     ad.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1     ac3.msn.com
127.0.0.1     ec.atdmt.com
127.0.0.1     msntest.serving-sys.com
127.0.0.1     sO.2mdn.net
127.0.0.1     aka-cdn-ns.adtech.de
127.0.0.1     secure.flashtalking.com
127.0.0.1     cdn.atdmt.com
```